# Change Gradient Color Stops in Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I want to apply gradient on canvas background. (Some text is written on canvas which is on Front)
I added rect of same size on canvas &  apply gradient on that rect.

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          width: canvas.width,
          height: canvas.height,      
          selectable: false
        });
    canvas.add(rect);
    canvas.sendToBack(rect);        
    rect.setGradient('fill',{
      type: 'linear',
      x1: 0,
      y1: 0,
      x2: rect.width,
      y2: rect.height,
      colorStops: {
        0: $('#grdColor1').val(),
        1: $('#grdColor2').val()
      }
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.setActiveObject(text);
```

*`#grdColor1 & #grdColor1` are input fields which allow user to apply colors.*
This code is working fine. 
But i want to further change colors of ColorStops from input of colors. So user can select & change gradient colors dynamically afterwards too.

I tried this but its not working:

```
$("#grdColor1").on('change', function(){
    o = canvas.item(0); //rect is set to back
    o.colorStops({
            0: $('#grdColor1').val(),
            1: $('#grdColor2').val(),
          });
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

**Also tried rect.colorStops but no success**.

Even further i want to change values of setGradient function "Linear" "Radial" "x1" "x2" etc. So user can dynamically set gradient options as per choice & colors.
**What is the method to change the values of setGradient afterwards.**

***EDIT***
**also tried :**

```
    $("#grdColor1").on('change', function() {
    rect.setGradient('fill',{
        colorStops: { //set colorStops again
            0: $('#grdColor1').val(),
            1: $('#grdColor2').val()
        }
    });
   });
```

I think its not selecting the rect object 
since i send it to back and selected text object afterwards:

```
canvas.sendToBack(rect);
canvas.setActiveObject(text);
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

```
var r = canvas.item(0);
r.setGradient('fill',{  
    colorStops: {
        0: $('#grdColor1').val(),
        1: $('#grdColor2').val()
    }
});
canvas.renderAll();
```

now rect is selecting but gradient is not applied properly.
with this code rect background is changing to single color #grdColor1 only i.e. no gradient effect.

Comment: setGradient() again?

Comment: I want to change colors of already set Gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the setGradient on change of `grdColor1` like,

```
$("#grdColor1").on('change', function(){;
   rect.setGradient('fill',{
      colorStops: { //set colorStops again
          0: $('#grdColor1').val(),
          1: $('#grdColor2').val()
      }
   });
    canvas.renderAll(); // now render
});
```

Update try this,

```
var r = canvas.item(0);
r.setGradient('fill',{
    type: 'linear',
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: r.width,
    y2: r.height,
    colorStops: {
       0: $('#grdColor1').val(),
       1: $('#grdColor2').val()
    }
});
canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: Thanks rohan i tried that too but i think problem is that code is not selecting the rect object properly.

Comment: Your `rect` variable should be global, in that case. Can you show an online demo for it like on fiddle.

Comment: check UPDATE in ques. now able to select rect object. change reflecting but only background color of rect change with #grdColor1 no gradient effect appears.

Comment: thanks its working now. x2: r.width,  y2: r.height is the perfect solution. i was checking another solution. fabric.js contain another function addColorStop